# List of prime numbers

Tags: list, f#

```
let liczby_pierw n x =
x = n || x % n <> 0

    let rec usuń listn listx =
        match listn with
        | głowa :: ogon ->  usuń ogon (List.filter (liczby_pierw głowa) listx)
        | [] -> listx
    
    let liczby_pierw1 n =
        let max = int (sqrt(float n)) 
        usuń [ 2 .. max ] [ 2.. n ]
    printfn "Liczby pierwsze od 2 do %d:\n %A" 100 (liczby_pierw1 100)
```

I have no idea how we can call a function with one parameter at this point | głowa :: ogon ->  usuń ogon (List.filter **(liczby_pierw głowa)** listx) , since that function was declared above as a function with two parameters.

I would like someone to explain to me how this works, why we could use a function call with one argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is called *partial function application*. When you have a function with multiple parameters, you can call it with just first few and the result will be a function that takes the remaining parameters.

When you write:

```
usuń ogon (List.filter (liczby_pierw głowa) listx)
```

It is actually the same as writing:

```
usuń ogon (List.filter (fun x -> liczby_pierw głowa x) listx)
```

The result of calling `liczby_pierw głowa` is a function that expects one more parameter (a function of type `int -> bool`). This is the type of function that you need to pass to `filter` and so you can do that without explicit `fun`.

Comment: `let add x y= x + y
    let tmp = add 10
    Console.WriteLine("Adding with one argument = {0}", tmp) //Here the function is waiting for the second argument as I got a strange message in the console. Do I understand it correctly?
    let tmp2 = tmp 20
    Console.WriteLine("Adding with all arguments  = {0}", tmp2)`

Comment: Yeah - in the first case, you got a strange message because you are trying to print a function value - which is some kind of object that cannot be nicely printed.